# Object doesn't get motion blur in several frames

Tags: rendering, constraints, inverse-kinematics, motion-blur

[image: robot animation]
I made a robot animation with IK rig. After rendering, as you can see on image 2 & 4, the robot didn't get motion blur at all but the furniture still get the motion blur. image 1 & 3 works fine. I use "Child Of" constraint to connect furniture to the robot.

Closer look:

[image: robot animation2]

Motion blur setting:

[image: motion blur setting]

Am I missing something?

Blender version: 2.79

Render engine: Cycles

Comment: Suggest adding a  screenshot of motion-blur settings.

Comment: I just added the motion-blur settings screenshot.